# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages button is not working

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor pPages project. And I probably use button for me script.

I have this html markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="progress" style="display:none">
        <h4>Loading...</h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this script:

```
function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: './Index?handler=ListOfPhoto',
            data: { "pageindex": pageIndex, "pagesize": pageSize },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var row = data[i];                        

                        var html = '<img src="/Photos/' + row.idUser + '/' + row.imageName + '" class="img-responsive" />';
                        html += '<h2>' + row.name + '</h2>';

                        html += '<form method="POST"> <button type="submit" asp-route-data="foo" asp-page-handler="Way">Way</button> </form>';

                        $("#container").append(html);

                    }
                    pageIndex++;
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#progress").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#progress").hide();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
```

But this button is not working:

```
html += '<form method="POST"> <button type="submit" asp-route-data="foo" asp-page-handler="Way">Way</button> </form>';
```

Handler method:

```
public void OnPostWay(string data)
{                
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas, why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to append html which is not html but it is a tag helper. The framework will take the asp-route-data and asp-page-handler in order to generate the formaction of the button.

In your example you have to generate the formaction yourself so you have to replace your button with the following code.

```
html += '<form method="POST"> <button type="submit" formaction="/YourPageName?data=foo&amp;handler=Way">Way</button> </form>';
```

Comment: Thank you!
But I have another problem. When I Click my button - have this error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value "RequestVerificationToken".
   в Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()

Comment: This is because you have to put the antiforgery token in your form.